# What are black belt and black glasses used for?

Tags: unova-rpg

Pokémon game UnovaRpg's shop offer a lot of items in its store for the Pokémon. The items include pokeballs, stones, TM/HMs and others. In the other section there is some pretty weird stuff like black belt and black glasses. I am wondering if these items cannot be used on Pokémon. If so then what are these items for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are hold items for pokemon.

Black belt boost the power of Fighting-type moves by 20% when held.

Blackglasses boost the power of Dark-type moves by 20% when held.

from http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Type-enhancing_item

Boost those STAB attacks NOW!